# How do you display selected images onto canvas using Fabric.js and Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, fabricjs

I am using **Fabric.js, Ruby on Rails, Jquery, and Ruby Gems** like **Carrierwave** to build my canvas application. I use CarrierWave to assist on storing my images in the database and I use Ruby's .each iterator to display the images on the page(see below).(don't let photo_pic confuse you, just a name I selected as the carrierwave downloader)

**This Code below works perfectly** and is exactly what I need and How I would like to display and store my images (There will be close to a thousand of them).

```
<div id="coupon_logos">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="550"></canvas>
 <% @images.each do |m| %>
  <%= image_tag m.photo_pic.url, :class => "my-image",  %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
```

**The PROBLEM** 
 
I wrote a function alongside fabric.js to display the image I want into the canvas.(see below) It does not work, I would like the user to click any image from the iteration and have that particular image display onto the canvas. **For Example,** if the user clicks the 10th image I want that image to display onto the canvas. (this code almost gets me there)

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
 $(".coupon_logos").on('click',function() {
  var imgElement = document.getElementsByClassName("my-image")
  var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
   left: 50,
   top: 50,
 });
 canvas.add(imgInstance);
 });
```

**FYI** With the code above I am not able to get a image to display but if i put **[4]** at the end of

```
var imgElement = document.getElementsByClassName("my-image")**[4]**
```

**The 4th image from the data bas will display** and that all makes sense of course. But I don't know how to display the image the user specifically selected. **I have tried everything.** From from Event handlers, and numerous google groups as resources but No one has been able to figure this out.

**Please Help**. This is one of those pull out hair moments bc It seems like a easy fix but I just cant get passed it(I'm forgetting something). Also, tips on a different title would be appreciated. I think this could help **NUMEROUS** people who are building Fabric.js frontend and Ruby Backend Applications. **All the Best Everyone,Stay Awesome **